# In Clojure's YeSQL, how can I *unload* loaded queries started from defqueries - to accommodate a Component Workflow?

Tags: clojure

Here's `defqueries`:

https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql/blob/master/src/yesql/core.clj#L6

And the `create-root-var` that instantiates the fns:

https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql/blob/master/src/yesql/util.clj#L27

I like the workflow promoted by Component, and I like YeSQL, but `defqueries` has trouble resetting appropriately when the rest of the program resets.

So, I'd like to stick it in a `Component`, and I get how to `start` it, but, I'm not as familiar with manipulating namespaces programatically to kick out all of the functions which get side-effected into existence.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove functions and symbols with ns-unmap, e.g. `(ns-unmap 'namespace 'symbol)`

Comment: good advice, but how do I find the symbol's which YeSQL makes, in order to use your solution, any thoughts?

Comment: Use `(keys (ns-publics 'my-namespace))` on the namespace in which you're running `defqueries`